# Using R to select individual resources that optimizes group effects to meet certain thresholds

Tags: r, optimization

See the following for a list of all constraints and references. Using R code, I would like to create an optimization that selects people (“A”,”B”,”C”) in order to maximize the number of products where the entire group sum can meet certain thresholds (mostly above threshold, a few below). So whether or not a person should be included is dependent on the context of the rest of the group. Note the constraints on the people (at least 3 must be selected from FL), and exactly 10 have to be selected that meet the “Other” criteria, etc.

I tried to set this up using the lpsolve package, but I don’t believe this can be solved with linear optimization. I’m a bit lost now, looking for any guidance here. I have used the nloptr package but I’m completely lost on how to set something like this up. I have included all the data below. Thanks for the consideration!

[image: Picture of all constraints and targeted values]

```
    TX  NY  MA  DE  FL  LA  Other   SW  CA  NV      Include? BINARY VALID EXAMPLE       Product 1   Product 2   Product 3   Product 4   Product 5   Product 6   Product 7   Product 8   Product 9   Product 10
A   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0       1   1       63  21  64  5   0.349   0   0   0   0   0
B   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0       1   1       89  31  98  6   0.361   0   0   0   0   0
C   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0       1   1       83  19  76  7   0.351   0   0   0   0   0
D   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0       1   1       100 38  103 2   0.349   0   0   0   0   0
E   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0       1   1       83  9   62  34  0.343   0   0   0   0   0
F   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0       1   1       98  33  93  28  0.346   0   0   0   0   0
G   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0       1   1       99  43  106 6   0.394   0   0   0   0   0
H   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0       1   1       86  19  65  4   0.363   0   0   0   0   0
I   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0       1   1       81  23  73  22  0.318   0   0   0   0   0
J   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0       1   1       57  21  69  1   0.32    0   0   0   0   0
K   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0       1   0       72  18  70  2   0.354   0   0   0   0   0
L   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1       1   1       0   0   0   0   0   3.44    1.12    10  178 0
M   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1       1   1       0   0   0   0   0   3.65    1.16    10  152 0
N   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0       1   1       0   0   0   0   0   2.72    1.05    3   96  35
O   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0       1   1       0   0   0   0   0   2.94    1.13    4   78  33
P   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1       1   1       0   0   0   0   0   3.57    1.09    12  171 0
Q   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1       1   1       0   0   0   0   0   3.71    1.14    11  194 0
R   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1       1   1       0   0   0   0   0   4.13    1.21    8   142 0
S   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1       1   1       0   0   0   0   0   3.97    1.16    9   138 0
T   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0       1   0       0   0   0   0   0   3.39    1.13    4   68  21
U   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1       1   0       0   0   0   0   0   3.34    1.16    2   78  22
V   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1       1   0       0   0   0   0   0   4.19    1.25    7   121 0
W   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1       1   0       0   0   0   0   0   3.99    1.28    10  129 0
X   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1       1   0       0   0   0   0   0   3.32    1.14    2   35  0
Y   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1       1   0       0   0   0   0   0   3.75    1.2 4   53  0
Z   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1       1   0       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
AA  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1       1   0       0   0   0   0   0   3.54    1.14    2   39  0
AB  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1       1   0       0   0   0   0   0   4.43    1.34    3   60  0
AC  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1       1   0       0   0   0   0   0   3.98    1.29    2   59  0
```

Comment: Perhaps you should be looking at integer programming. In any case this is insufficiently specific to be a programming question. Voting to migrate.